# Be Nice - A Simple Reminder

Tags: discussion

At times there are a series of incidents where people have started being quite confrontational and generally unpleasant to other users. I don't want to call anyone out or mention any specifics but can everyone read and understand the SE [community "Be nice" policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice):

> ### **Be nice**.
>
> Whether you've come to ask questions, or to generously share what you
> know, remember that we’re all here to learn, together. Be welcoming
> and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do.
> Oh, and bring your sense of humor. Just in case.
>
> That basically covers it. But these three guidelines may help:
>
> 1. **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should
>    match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom
>    you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something
>    politely, just leave it for someone who does.
> 2. **Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.** Don't expect
>    new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while
>    they learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for
>    others to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one
>    responds well to demands for help.
> 3. **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them,
>    flag them:
>
> - **Name-calling.** Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms     that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like
>   "lazy",      "ignorant", or "whiny").
> - **Bigotry of any kind.** Language likely to offend or alienate    individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation,
>   religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few
>   examples; when in doubt, just don't.)
> - **Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything    sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.
> - **Harassment and bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, flag it.    If it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs
>   staff    attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of
>   every    page.
>
> We're proud to be a large, user-driven space on the internet where
> name-calling, harassment, and other online nastiness are almost
> non-existent. It's up to all of us to keep it that way.
>
> **In summary, be Christian, and be of good cheer to each other.**
>
> **Generally I think we are an incredibly open and helpful community** (much more so than other communities on the SE network <sup><sub>cough...Stackoverflow....cough</sub></sup>). So I don't think we have a big problem but there seems to be a slight trend with some individuals towards not being as nice as we should be. So I wanted to prompt a quick reminder for some of the newer members.
>
> [Source](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/be-nice-a-reminder)

Comment: Up-voted +1. A timely reminder for us all.

Comment: So... the Bible isn't a cudgel for beating sense into people. Good to know :)

Comment: @Machavity Nor is a hammer. But, sadly. some people buy a hammer with the intent of doing harm to others. And some people buy bibles to do what you describe. Such is human nature.

Comment: where did your quote actually come from? some of these points are found on the code of conduct but not in this format and not with all these details

Comment: @depperm  See [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/be-nice-a-reminder)

Comment: I would suggest you distribute hard copies of this to your staff regularly (i.e. regularly). Though I do wonder why "Christians" even need this as a reminder.

Answer (score 2):

What you say is true though, thankfully, episodes of unpleasant statements are quite rare (unless you know something that I don't?!?) What I've noticed is that the 'Comments' section seems most likely to lead into not being nice, especially if there's a plethora of comments, some that seem to be hoping to goad another person into retaliating.

I just mention this in order to support Moderators who eventually clamp down on  Comment 'threads'. So often, those threads delve into issues not directly related to the actual question asked. And it's usually in Comment boxes that a participant will express offense they have taken at someone holding to a different view, or of  being thumbed-down, when, really, that's just par for the course.

While I would not go so far as to invoke the saying, "If you can't stand the heat, stay out of the kitchen", I would say that when some individuals get a bit heated, others should respond in a kindly way, or just ignore their hot remarks. (I've learned that the hard way, through experience!) And, it's always good to know that the Moderators are standing by, fire-extinguishers in hand!